# Use only 1 regexp operation to replace "Add or Remove Programs" with "fnAdd_or_Remove_Programs_button_clicked"

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to use a single regular expression match and replace operation to transform the text string 
    "Add or Remove Programs" into
    "fnAdd_or_Remove_Programs_button_clicked".

For my Match expression, I used:    ([A-Za-z0-9]+)( |$)
For my Replace expression, I used:  \g<1>_

Let's refer to the search and replace operation as "My_Partial_Op"

My_Partial_Op produced the result:  Add_or_Remove_Programs_

I want to insert a prefix "fn" before the result above and add the suffix "button_clicked" at the end of the result above.

I know that I could get my desired end product by performing two regular expression search and replace operations:

1. My_Partial_Op, and
2. Insert a prefix "fn" before the product produced by My_Partial_Op and add the suffix "button_clicked" at the end of the product produced by My_Partial_Op.

But I would like to know if it's possible to get my desired end result in one regexp search and replace operation.

Any suggestions about how to do it, or where to learn more about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a challenge of some kind? I don't think it can be done with a single replacement operation.

Comment: If your input string is only _Add or Remove Programs_, then you can hardcode the replacement expression. Otherwise, this is not a job for regex as the 4 words have the same structure (1 or more letters or whatever) but you want to operate differently on each (i.e. you need a kind of if-then-elseif-then...).

Comment: To better express myself, I ask a question: how would you explain the difference between `Add`, `or`, `Remove`, and `Programs`, for which the first is prepended `fn`, the second, the third, and the fourth are prepended a `_`, and the fourth is also appended a `_button_clicked`?

Comment: To Barmar and Enrico Maria De Angelis: Thank you for responding. This was not a "challenge of some kind".  I try to keep my coding short by doing as few find and replace operations as possible.  I am not confident in my abilities as a coder (since I am not a professional coder ... yet.  I am in the process of retiring from being a lawyer) and I hoped that you experts would show me something I was missing.  Please tell me if my posting was inappropriate so that I do not misuse StackOverflow (again?).  Thanks you so much for your time & effort.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `print("fn{0}_button_clicked".format(re.sub(r"([A-Za-z0-9]+) ", r"\g<1>_", "Add or Remove Programs")))` See https://ideone.com/rptGNq